# How to open this WWF shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I would like to display the following [data](http://www.worldwildlife.org/publications/global-lakes-and-wetlands-database-lakes-and-wetlands-grid-level-3) in ArcGis. It downloads very fast, but I can't seem to open them in ArcGis. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you having problem with only this shapefile? can you open other shapefiles? What error do you see?

Comment: When you say that you "can't seem to open them in ArcGis", what do you mean?  If there is an error message can you include it in your question, please?

Comment: Actually, I am starting to doubt whether these are real shapefiles. It says: "This raster data source does not have pyramids or contains insufficient pyramids. Pyramids allow for rapid dispaly at varying resolutions."

Comment: Then it would appear as your data is in a raster format, not shapefiles. Did you click somewhere in Arcmap when you loaded it? That could result in incomplete pyramid files. Try removing the .ovr file and load again, but don't click anywhere until the raster is displayed!

Answer (score 2):

From manual page http://www.gdal.org/drv_avcbin.html

> If the directory contains files with names like w001001.adf then the
>   coverage is a grid coverage suitable to read with GDAL, not a vector
>   coverage supported by OGR.

Data seems to contain .adf, continue by reading http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#AIG

Having a try with gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -of gtiff hdr.adf arc.tif
Input file size is 43200, 21600
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Resulting tiff file "arc.tif" is georeferenced and it can be opened with image viewers and QGIS. However, it is a grey scale image and for finding the classes you must classify the image by the pixel values. Perhaps ESRI products can make the classification automatically.

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000010,  90.0000010)
Lower Left  (-180.0000010, -90.0000084)
Upper Right ( 180.0000178,  90.0000010)
Lower Right ( 180.0000178, -90.0000084)
Center      (   0.0000084,  -0.0000037)
Band 1 Block=256x4 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=1.000 Max=12.000
  NoData Value=255
```

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, I only need to read the .adf file. All the other once do not have to be uploaded. They just need to be saved in the right directory?

Comment: I do not know really. That is something that comes from arc/info era. What I did was to unzip the whole file and without touching anything point GDAL to read the hdr.adf file. It seems to scan the whole directory and find other files as well but not from the "info" directory `Files: .
       .\dblbnd.adf
       .\hdr.adf
       .\metadata.xml
       .\sta.adf
       .\vat.adf
       .\w001001.adf
       .\w001001x.adf`